# VS2017 "tsc.exe" exited with code

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core

I am using VS2017 and I have troubles with typescript compilation  Typescript version is 2.2.3. I have also installed Typescript.Compiler, Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler, TypeScript.MSBuildTask following other topics where installing these packages resolved the issue. I saw that a lot of people get this error but in VS15 and the solutions don't work for me.

> The error is MSB6006 "tsc.exe" exited with code 1.

When I double click it references this code

```
<Target Name="CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig"
    Condition="'$(BuildingProject)' != 'false' AND '@(ConfigFiles)' != ''"
    DependsOnTargets="$(CompileTypeScriptDependsOn)">
    <VsTsc
      ToolPath="$(TscToolPath)"
      ToolExe="$(TscToolExe)"
      IsFileSystemCaseSensitive="$(IsFileSystemCaseSensitive)"
      TSJavaScriptFile="$(TSJavaScriptFile)"
      PreferredUILang="$(PreferredUILang)"
      TSConfigFile="%(ConfigFiles.Identity)"
      YieldDuringToolExecution="$(TscYieldDuringToolExecution)"
      ProjectDir="$(TypeScriptProjectDir)"
      ToolsVersion="$(TypeScriptEffectiveToolsVersion)"
      TypeScriptCompileBlocked="$(TypeScriptCompileBlocked)"
      ComputeOutputOnly="false"
      OutputLogFile="$(CompilerOutputLog)">

      <Output TaskParameter="GeneratedJavascript" ItemName="emittedFiles" />
    </VsTsc>
    <ItemGroup>
      <GeneratedJavascript Include="@(emittedFiles)" KeepDuplicates="false" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <AssignTargetPath Files="@(GeneratedJavascript)" RootFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)">
      <Output TaskParameter="AssignedFiles" ItemName="GeneratedJavascriptWithTargetPath" />
    </AssignTargetPath>
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="@(GeneratedJavascriptWithTargetPath->'%(Identity)')"/>
      <ContentWithTargetPath Include="@(GeneratedJavascriptWithTargetPath->'%(Identity)')"/>
      <Content Include="@(GeneratedJavascript->'%(Identity)')"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

This is my tsConfig following the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2017:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "out"
  },
  "exclude": [
    [ "wwwroot/lib" ],
    "out"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you transpile it from the command-line or do you get similar errors? Also, try it without the tsconfig (just using the Visual Studio properties) and see what you get.